# Getting Google Plus Info on Backend Server In Java

Tags: javascript, java, google-oauth

I want to use google plus sign in for my web application. Till now i am using java script code to get id_token from the Google

```
function renderButton() {
      gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
        'scope': 'profile email',
        'longtitle': true,
        'onfailure': onFailure,
        'onsuccess': onSignIn
 } );
```

And Passing it to Back end to verify the id_token and getting details of user using

```
 String email = payload.getEmail();
  boolean emailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(payload.getEmailVerified());
  String name = (String) payload.get("name");
  String pictureUrl = (String) payload.get("picture");
  String locale = (String) payload.get("locale");
  String familyName = (String) payload.get("family_name");
  String givenName = (String) payload.get("given_name");
```

Now i want gender and age and other public information at  java side ,How can i get it,Most of the method i came across are using javascript at client side.